# How to change dynamic template loading code to 0.8 version of Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about to change the dynamic template loading code to 0.8 version of meteor.i didn't get any idea about this.So please see the below code and suggest me what to do for this?

Html code :

```
<template name="content">

  {{ renderTemplate}}

</template>
```

JS code :

```
Template.content.helpers

({
    'renderTemplate': function()

    {
       if(Session.get('ContentTemplate') == undefined)

       {
         Session.set('ContentTemplate', 'main');

       }

        return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('ContentTemplate')]({dataKey: '0'}));

    }

 })
```

Comment: Have you considered using Iron Router?

Comment: No , I'm not using the Iron router.@sbking

Comment: But in need with loading depends on using sessions.@sbking